# How to set get the Token for using Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

We are exploring the use of Graph API in order to automate the process of an onBoarding user from a Jira Service Request.
Final solution will be to use the REST API calls from a script Runner in a Jira workflow

For now we are simply testing the different way to add a user to a group in our AD account in Azure
This works nicely when using Graph Explorer and sign-In to our account.

Now we would like to test the same without sign-in but passing authentication to the HTTP request Header.

We are actually confuse on what should we pass in the Header in order to make the call directly through POSTMAN for instance .

Is it the subscription ID, or something else ?
In document it is mentionned a token ID but can we find this token in our Azure Account ?

Thanks for clarification on this where to find those authentication parameter that we need in order to be passed in Request Header.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the Bearer Token to the HTTP Header, you can get the Token from **AcquireTokenAsync**. Here is a simple Microsoft.Graph API example with ClientId + ClientSecret:

```
// Create AuthenticationContext with ClientId + ClientSecret
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/token");
var creds = new ClientCredential("AzureIDClientID", "AzureADClientSecret");

// gets a Token
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", creds);

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage
       .Headers
       .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.Result.AccessToken);

return Task.FromResult(0);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pbacham but I am not using any programing language actually in such way you mentionned to get this token.
We would like to simply copy paste the required token inside the Header of the POSTMAN Get request simply...Does this token can bee seen on my Azure AD account through the Regisered application list 
?